# how to make table rows slide fade in/fade out continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, slide

I have a table with 6 rows (or data), I want first load show 2 rows data then fade out and showing next rows 2 rows again and fade out again then show next rows 2 rows again continuously every (n) seconds

here is the code of table

```
<table border>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>naslov1</th>
        <th>naslov2</th>
        <th>naslov3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tableslide">
    <tr>
        <td>test_@0</td>
        <td>test_@0</td>
        <td>test_@0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test_@1</td>
        <td>test_@1</td>
        <td>test_@1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test_@2</td>
        <td>test_@2</td>
        <td>test_@2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test_@3</td>
        <td>test_@3</td>
        <td>test_@3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test_@4</td>
        <td>test_@4</td>
        <td>test_@4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test_@5</td>
        <td>test_@5</td>
        <td>test_@5</td>
    </tr></tbody>
```

I was tried on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gtd4f5ny/28/ but its just slide 2 times and I want make it 3 times every 2 rows every (n) seconds.
Please help guys. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried yourself to create this? Please keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a coding service

Comment: I have tried like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gtd4f5ny/28/ but its just make slide 2 times but I want make it 3 times every 2 rows every N seconds. how ?

Comment: Here is an helping hand to you  http://jsfiddle.net/gtd4f5ny/29/ .. This is what you want with 1 row, now you should be able to change it to work with 2 rows.

Comment: "I want make it 3 times every 2 rows every (n) seconds" is not very clear. Can you describe it more..

Comment: @Teddy you can see the fiddle

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thank you for your respone I will try it

Comment: You won't be loading any new data? Only what is there in the table in HTML you want to cycle through the rows, showing only 2 rows at a time? Like [0,1] then [2,3] then [4,5] then [0,1] then [2,3] and so on?

Comment: What if there are 7 rows? Do you want it to [0,1] then [2,3] then [4,5] then [6,0] then [1,2] (or) [0,1] then [2,3] then [4,5] then [6] and back to [0,1]

Comment: if 7 rows the last one just show [7] then back to [0,1] again and so on

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I give up I very new on this how to make it work with 2 rows ?

Comment: I added an answer for [0,1] then [2,3] then [4,5] then [0,6]. Hope you can fix the last part to make it [6] and [0,1]. @coder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```js
$(function () {
 var $tableslide = $("#tableslide");
  var rows = $("#tableslide").children().length;
  var iterCount = 0;
  var lastPairSel = null;
  $("#tableslide").children().hide();

 setInterval(function () {
   var start = iterCount*2 % rows;
    var next = (iterCount*2 + 1) % rows;
    var startSel = 'tr:nth-child(' + (start+1) + ')';
    var nextSel = 'tr:nth-child(' + (next+1) + ')';
    var pairSel = startSel + ',' + nextSel;
    console.log(pairSel);
    

$tableslide.children( lastPairSel ).fadeOut().promise().then(function () {
   $tableslide.children( pairSel ).fadeIn();
          lastPairSel = pairSel;

  });
   
    iterCount++;
    
    
 }, 3000);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>naslov1</th>
            <th>naslov2</th>
            <th>naslov3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableslide">
        <tr>
            <td>test_@0</td>
            <td>test_@0</td>
            <td>test_@0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test_@1</td>
            <td>test_@1</td>
            <td>test_@1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test_@2</td>
            <td>test_@2</td>
            <td>test_@2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test_@3</td>
            <td>test_@3</td>
            <td>test_@3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test_@4</td>
            <td>test_@4</td>
            <td>test_@4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test_@5</td>
            <td>test_@5</td>
            <td>test_@5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test_@6</td>
            <td>test_@6</td>
            <td>test_@6</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

**Edit:**

Changing this fixes the [0,6] problem:

```
var start = iterCount*2 % rows;
var next = start+1; //If next is unavailable index, it will be ignored
```

If "n at a time" is dynamic:

```
    $(function () {
        var $tableslide = $("#tableslide");
        var rows = $("#tableslide").children().length;
        var start = 0;
        var lastPairSel = null;
        $("#tableslide").children().hide();

        setInterval(function () {
            var n = 4;
            var pairSel = '';
            for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
                if(start+i > rows) break; //Optional. To skip unwanted selectors
                if(i>0) pairSel+=',';
                pairSel += 'tr:nth-child(' + (start+i+1) + ')'
            }
            console.log(pairSel);

            $tableslide.children( lastPairSel ).fadeOut().promise().then(function () {
                $tableslide.children( pairSel ).fadeIn();
                lastPairSel = pairSel;
            });

            start = (start + n);
            if(start>rows) start = 0;
        }, 3000);  
    });
```

Comment: Thanks alot you save my time, just one question if I want change it to be [0,1,2]  and so on. how ?

Comment: If it's just 3 at a time, add one more variable. If it would be dynamic then use a inner loop to construct pairSel

Comment: Updated with dynamic option

Comment: Hope it solves your query... Please do accept the answer if it did. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Javascript to do that and move the data to Javascript. Simplest way is to create DOM nodes and add it to tbody after time interval.

1. Move all data to JavaScript variable.
2. Create a function add a single row to body
3. Add rows in a setInterval

```js
const data = [
  ["testa1", "testa2", "testa3"],
  ["testb1", "testb2", "testb3"],
  ["testc1", "testc2", "testc3"],
  ["testd1", "testd2", "testd3"],
  ["teste1", "teste2", "teste3"],
  ["testf1", "testf2", "testf3"]
];

function addRow(tbody, data) {
  const row = document.createElement("tr");
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const td = document.createElement("td");
    td.textContent = data[i];
    row.appendChild(td);
  }
  tbody.appendChild(row);
}
function cleartData(elem){
  while (elem.firstChild) {
    elem.removeChild(elem.firstChild);
}
}
const tbody = document.querySelector("#tableslide");
let counter = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  cleartData(tbody);
  addRow(tbody, data[counter]);
  addRow(tbody, data[counter + 1]);
  counter = (counter + 2) % data.length;
}, 2000);
```

```html
<table border >
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>naslov1</th>
        <th>naslov2</th>
        <th>naslov3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tableslide">
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the code for reference

https://codepen.io/akmittal/pen/bQjQgP

Comment: can you make it simple without move the data to javascript ? sorry because its difficult for me I very new on this